# Mejorar rendimiento google datastudio

Tags: mysql, sql, google-data-studio

tengo un portal de datastudio del cual recojo datos por el conector mysql a mi base de datos, el tema es que da muchos errores, y cada dos por tres cada vez que miro el portal sale este error.

`Failed to execute connection with error: User db_user already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections`

¿Alguien sabe tips/consejos o sabe por que se da esto y que se puede hacer para mejorarlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Cuando lo investigaste en google, cuáles palabras utilizaste? Al parecer, el usuario tiene un número máximo de conexiones permitidas. Sabes si las conexiones se están cerrando correctamente? Si tienes permisos suficientes, sabes si puedes incrementar el número de conexiones desde el motor de base de datos? En fin, qué has intentado?